# localStorage is being emptied a lot

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using JWT for authentication that I store in localStorage. What I notice is that chrome is deleting all the localStorage data every ~15minutes or so. Is there something I can do about this?

I'm using https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth for frontend JWT and https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth for backend JWT validation

Comment: Please share the code you are using with us.

Comment: You should define what version of Chrome and/or steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: *"What I notice is that chrome is deleting all the localStorage data every ~15minutes or so."* That seems unlikely. It's more likely something in your code or JWT is doing so.

Comment: why do yo want to remove localstorage data every 15min?

Comment: check where your code delete the localStorage after 15min, because localStorage by definition has not expiration date!

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth for frontend JWT and https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth for backend JWT validation